Error obtaining Endpoints for Service "default/marketplace-service": no object matching key "default/test-service" in local store
Im getting this error I have checked my ingress it is showing me this :
 /api/test            test-service:8001 (<error: endpoints "test-service" not found>)
but when I'm checking endpoints the service has endpoints.
test-service            10.2.0.198:8001   77m
the pods and service are in a particular namespace also i tried giving namespace in ingress but it is throwing error please help
the service is of type ClusterIP
I want to access my service on this path using my ingress
this is my ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
  name: nginx-ingress
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /api/test
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: test-service 
                port:
                  number: 8006


If you kubectl describe service test-service, there's a line at the end that says Endpoints:; does that list anything?  If it says <none> then the Service's selector doesn't match your Deployment, and that could lead to an error like this.

it is showing the endpoint but when i describe ingress it not showing
